# Replace function returning string with repeated characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

consider following function

```js
function myFunction() {
  var html = "CR_557!#$&amp;'()*+,-./:;&lt;=&gt;?@[]^_`{|}";
  var data = html.substring(0, 14);
  var newData = '<span style="background-color:#F2E9B7">' + data + '</span>';
  return html.replace(data, newData);
}

console.log(myFunction());
```

the expected content for var `html` in the end should be:

```
"<span style=\"background-color:#F2E9B7\">CR_557!#$&amp;</span>'()*+,-./:;&lt;=&gt;?@[]^_`{|}"
```

but for some reason i am getting this:

```
"<span style=\"background-color:#F2E9B7\">CR_557!#CR_557!#$&amp;amp;</span>'()*+,-./:;&lt;=&gt;?@[]^_`{|}"
```

the characters CR_557!# are getting repeated for some reason
not sure why.

Comment: It also repeats `&amp;` with `&amp;amp;`...

Comment: `$&` has a special meaning when used with `String.prototype.replace()`: _"`$&` Inserts the matched substring."_ ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Andreas mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61523299/replace-function-returning-string-with-repeated-characters-in-javascript/61523687#comment108830136_61523299), [`$&` has a special meaning in the replacement parameter of `String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/string/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

To solve the problem, use [a `function` as the replacement parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/string/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var html = "CR_557!#$&amp;'()*+,-./:;&lt;=&gt;?@[]^_`{|}";
  var data = html.substring(0, 14);
  var newData = '<span style="background-color:#F2E9B7">' + data + '</span>';
  return html.replace(data, function () { return newData  });
}

console.log(myFunction());
```